# Ambiance seemingly uninstalled after Update

Tags: unity, compiz, ambiance

Problem: Updated on 30/07/2012 (no idea what was updated, noticed a lot of updates to Qt), restarted, and was greeted with a broken, painful looking desktop.

Tried `$ unity --reset`

But system complained - "Window Manager warning: Failed to load theme "Ambiance": Failed to find a valid file for theme Ambiance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by reinstalling Ambiance with the following command, and restarting the computer.

`sudo apt-get install light-themes`